# Move to the next screen in a condition?

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, screen, nsxmlparser

I don't know if the approach is correct: I made a SOAP call to WebService that is initiated by pressing on a button. After the call, it parsed with the response. Now comes the question: if the response is "OK", step to the next screen with the answer you get.
How can I do? The piece of code is the following:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?)
{
    if currentElementName == "ClientQRCodeMobileResult"
    {
        var wsResponse = string!
        var splittiamo = split(wsResponse) {$0 == ";"}
        var firstString: String = splittiamo[0]
        if splittiamo[0] == "OK"
        {
            var tmp = splittiamo[1].toInt()
            var tmpDouble = Double(tmp!)
            var tmpRound = Double(round(1.00*tmpDouble)/100.00)
            // Code HERE for next screen.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in firstString what the result u get

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Sorry, it is a variable unnecessary. I forgot to take it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not get in your question clearly ,so I submit in my answer is assumption

```
    var b =string!

 func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?)
{
   if firstString == "OK"
    {
        var tmp = splittiamo[1].toInt()
        var tmpDouble = Double(tmp!)
        var tmpRound = Double(round(1.00*tmpDouble)/100.00)
        // Code HERE for next screen.

       b= String(format:"%f", tmpRound)
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("youridntifierName", sender: self)
    }
   else
    {
     // failure status
    }

}
```

want to pass data

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if segue.identifier == "youridntifierName" {

   let yourNextViewCOntroller = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
    yourNextViewCOntroller.passString=b
}
```

in your `yourNextViewCOntroller` created the one object for pass data, like

```
 var passString:String!
```

additional [reference](http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/)

Comment: would you need assistance I hope with you

Comment: This assumes that OP uses stroyboard based navigation.

Comment: @Losiowaty - correct , we don't know exactly what the questioner need, if he say something I modify my answer

Comment: check my answer , u need modification/requirment tell me

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I try with your code, wait some minutes. ;)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Is it possible pass more than a variable to next screen using PrepareForSegue?

Comment: if you can pass variable, array, dictionary , etc,,, in here if you want to pass variable create another variable and do the same step